# TF10152: The item must remain locked because its file type prevents multiple check-outs

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am getting this error in TFS:

> `TF10152: The item csproj must remain locked because its file type
>   prevents multiple check-outs`.

The file is checked out to me. I cannot undo the checkout. I cannot unlock it either.

This is from the TFS output log in VS. I have removed the filenames to protect the innocent.

> TF10152: The item FILENAME.csproj must remain locked because its file
>   type prevents multiple check-outs. Warning - Unable to refresh
>   FILENAME.csproj because you have a pending edit. FILENAME.csproj has
>   been automatically checked out for editing. TF10152: The item
>   FILENAME.csproj must remain locked because its file type prevents
>   multiple check-outs.

**Edit**: I think it may be an issue with the Solution file. I am getting the following error when trying to get the latest version of the Solution file. It automatically checks that one out too:

> There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source
>   control information about some project(s) and the information in the
>   project file(s).
>
> To resolve this discrepancy it will be necessary to check out the
>   project file(s) and update them. If the check out fails, however, and
>   the solution is closed without saving, you will see this warning again
>   the next time you open the solution.

**Edit**: The solution file is having the same issue too. I compared the solution file with my workspace version and they are identical. The solution file is auto-checking itself out and I am getting the following message when I undo checkout:

> There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source
>   control information about some project(s) and the information in the
>   project file(s).
>
> To resolve this discrepancy it will be necessary to check out the
>   project file(s) and update them. If the check out fails, however, and
>   the solution is closed without saving, you will see this warning again
>   the next time you open the solution.

Comment: Do you have anything else checked out? If not you might consider EITHER deleting your workspace and recreating it or temporarily going into Team Foundation Source Control File Types and relaxing the restriction temporarily. I haven't encountered this issue but it is what I would try.

Comment: @MikeCheel - thanks for the suggestion. I have nothing checked out. Except for the project file which auto checks itself out to me for some reason. I have tried getting the latest version of the entire solution - no joy. I have compared my project file with the one in TFS and there are no changes.

Comment: I would be curious to know what you try and what works.

Comment: @MikeCheel Me too :-)

Comment: @MikeCheel Found the issue, VS had a lock on the folder that contained the project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the issue was. Visual Studio had a lock on the folder that contained the project file. It did not have the folder open in the foreground - somehow it had a lock on the folder in the background. When I closed that instance of Visual Studio and fired up a new one. I was able to undo checkouts without any issue!

Comment: Like a modal or something that is hidden?

Comment: @MikeCheel - not sure I did not have anything open in VS. It had a file lock or edit or similar on the folder - but it was in the background. It was not visible. It was weird. Anyway, the solution was like most MS products - a restart!

Comment: haha yea that is usually the first solution, I should have asked ha! And TFS can come up with some cryptic messages. I had a call open with Microsoft the other day because of issues with TFS and the fix was to clear the local tfs cache (which I have done plenty of times but didnt even think the issue at the time would be solved by that).Glad you fixed it.